# Javascript: How to set value to an object property inside an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

what is the correct way to write/read to a variable property of an object that is inside an array?

```
let exampleArray = [];
let exampleProperty = "string";
let exampleValue = 10;
let arrayRowIndex = 5;

exampleArray[arrayRow][exampleProperty] = exampleValue;   // this does not work
console.log( exampleArray[arrayRowIndex][exampleProperty] );
```

And how would this look if the object was inside an array of arrays? For example:

```
exampleArray[3][10].exampleObjecProperty
```

How would this look using variables for both indexes and the property itself?

Comment: _"// this does not work"_ - Why should it? `exampleArray` is empty...

Comment: _"And how would this look if the object was inside an array of arrays?"_ - Where an object is stored doesn't change how you add/change properties of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array really starts empty, you'll have to create any nested object. You may be looking for computed property names:

```
exampleArray[arrayRowIndex] = {
    [exampleProperty]: exampleValue
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my question. The online-guides and even my 400-page javascript book all only show examples of simple arrays and I was having some trouble figuring this out.

Will accept the question as soon as the time limit allows me to.

Comment: I had tried this:

exampleArray[arrayRowIndex] = {
    exampleProperty: exampleValue
}

but I was missing those [] around the "exampleProperty"